# Timezones and summer time in different states

Tags: php, email, date, datetime, timezone

I have a problem with PHP IMAP timezones.

I have a server that download emails from my users accounts. And than the users can view their email on my website.

I set the php timezone of my server to UTC 0 and now i want that my users see the receiving time of the emails to their timezones. But the problem is the summer time because the timezone change of 1 hour.

Example:

GMail give me an email with received time in UTC (0) at 7:00.

In Italy, the timezone is UTC +1 so i can add 1 hour to this time, then it will be 8:00.

But now in Italy we have the summer timezone so the UTC must be +2 not +1 but not all countries have this. So i ask if exists maybe a online service that can give me the correct offset that i must add to the hour for showing the correct time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can try: http://timezonedb.com/api

Comment: Alvaro is correct, you need to use geographical identifiers (aka IANA/Olson time zone ids).  See also the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), particularly the sections "Time Zone != Offset" and "The IANA/Olson Time Zone Database".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Italy the time zone swaps between CET and CEST so you cannot hard-code it using names that do not reflect this fact. You need to use geographical identifiers like `Europe/Rome`:

```
<?php

$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$rome = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome');

$winter = new DateTime('2013-12-31', $utc);
$summer = new DateTime('2013-08-31', $utc);

$winter->setTimezone($rome);
$summer->setTimezone($rome);

echo $winter->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
echo $summer->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
```

```
Tue, 31 Dec 2013 01:00:00 +0100
Sat, 31 Aug 2013 02:00:00 +0200
```